# Replacing ip address in kubernetes with custom name

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have created a sample spring boot app and did the following:-

1.created a docker image

2.created an Azure container registry and did a docker push to this

3.Created a cluster in Azure Kubernetes service and deployed it successfully.I have chosen external endpoint option for this.

[Kubernetes external end point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9dtB.png)

say for service to service call i dont want to use IP like http://20.37.134.68:80 but another custom name how can i do it?
Also if i chose internal then is there any way to replace the name.
Tried editing YAML with endpoint name property but failed.Any ideas?

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: by "change name" I assume you mean that you want to assign a DNS name to that IP address?!

Comment: ok let me explain.If i need a custom domain then i need to register rt.say if my ext endpoint is 1.1.1.1 then http://1.1.1.1/myapi runs for me.what i want is this pod that i have deployed should have http://theapp/myapi where theapp-->custom name.reason i may need to use this for say calling service to service calls.i tried nginx controller but facing certain issues.Any better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixing some concept, so I'll try to explain and help you to reach what you want.

1. When you deploy a container image in a Kubernetes cluster, in the most cases you will use a [`pod`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/) or [`deployment`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) spec, that basically is a yaml file with all your deployment/pod configuration, name, image name etc. Here is an example of a simple echo-server app:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: echo
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: echo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: echo
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: echo
        image: mendhak/http-https-echo
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
```

Observe the fields `name` in the file. Here you can configure the name for your deployment and for your containers.

2. In order to **expose** your application, you will need to use a [`service`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). Services can be `internal` and `external`. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) you can find all service types.

For a internal service, you need to use the service type `ClusterIP` (default), it means only your cluster will reach the pods. To reach your service from other pods, you can use the [service name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#srv-records) composed by `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster-domain.example`.

Here is an example of a service for the deployment above:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: echo-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: echo
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

3. To expose your service externally, you have the option to use a service type `NodePort`, `LoadBalancer` or use an [`ingress`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

You can configure your DNS name in the ingress rules and make path rules if you want, or even configure a HTTPS for your application. There are few options to ingresses in kubernetes, and one of the most popular is [`nginx-ingress`](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/).

Here is an example of how to configure a simple ingress for our example service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "false"
  name: echo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myapp.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: "/"
        backend:
          serviceName: echo-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

In the example, i'm using the dns name `myapp.mydomain.com`, so it means you can only will reach your application by this name.

After create the ingress, you can see the external ip with the command `kubectl get ing`, and you can create a A entry in your dns server.